# What does this logrotate nginx config do?

Tags: kill, daemon, signals, nginx, logrotate

In my `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx` I saw,

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 52
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 nginx adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                [ -f /var/run/nginx.pid ] && kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
        endscript
}
```

The postrotate script looks like killing the nginx process, which does not make sense so I must be wrong.

What it is doing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Nginx responds to the `USR1` signal](http://wiki.nginx.org/CommandLine#Stopping_or_Restarting_Nginx) by reopening its log files.

The USR1 signal kills a program by default, but it's meant to be handled to do whatever the program finds useful. Each program defines what it does with USR1 and USR2; for Nginx, that's reopening the log files (for log rotation) and executing a new instance (for upgrades).

By convention, most daemons respond to the HUP signal by reloading their configuration file. Nginx follows this convention. The original intent of the HUP signal was to signal the end of a session to interactive process (modem hang up — the user's gone, there's no point in continuing), but that meaning doesn't apply to daemons.

Answer (score 0):

The `kill` command generically sends POSIX signals to a process. The normal invocation sends `SIGTERM`, which asks a process to terminate. However, in your case the signal being sent is `SIGUSR1` which in your case, asks nginx to recycle its log files.